# POST request using QWebView request

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qwebview, qwebkit

Hi I'm working with pyqt4 and what I want to do is to craft an arbitrary POST request by using the QtWebKit request of my QWebPage/QWebView. By looking extensively around my understanding is that I have to subclass networkaccessmanager by overriding the `createRequest()` method.

I saw an example that allowed to use the fourth parameter of createRequest to extract the data of a POST request (see code below) being sent, but my question is how can I set that same data variable of createRequest to send a custom POST data, like "query=myvalue"?

Apparently data is a `QIODevice` variable: I tried a lot of different ways to set it, but can't get it to work and always end up with python complaining it's an unexpected value. Am I missing something here? Anybody care to share a working code sample?

```
import sys  
from PySide.QtCore import *  
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication  
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebView, QWebPage 
from PySide.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager

html = '''  <html>  <body> 
    <form action="http://www.google.com" method="post"><input type="text" name="test" /><input type="submit" value="submit"/></form>
</body>  </html>  ''' 

class Browser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.network_manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.network_manager.createRequest = self._create_request

        self.web_page = QWebPage()
        self.web_page.setNetworkAccessManager(self.network_manager)

        self.web_view = QWebView()
        self.web_view.setPage(self.web_page)

        self.html_data = None

    def _create_request(self, operation, request, data):
        # data contains all the post data that is being added to the request
        # so you can look into it here
        print data.readAll()
        reply = QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest(self.network_manager,
                                                    operation,
                                                    request,
                                                    data)
        return reply

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    app = QApplication(sys.argv) 
    browser = Browser() 
    frame = browser.web_page.mainFrame() 
    browser.web_view.setHtml(html) 
    browser.web_view.show() 
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Do you want to send a completly new POST request or modify the parameters of an existing one on the fly ?

Comment: For the sake of knowledge I'd love to know how to modify the parameters on the fly for an existing one now that I know how to send a brand new request. Feel free to post it here, I couldn't find specific help anywhere, so I'm sure it'll benefit someone else as well. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you posted is from one of my answers, so I feel obligated to answer this question too :)

```
from PySide.QtCore import QByteArray, QUrl
from PySide.QtGui import QApplication  
from PySide.QtWebKit import QWebView, QWebPage 
from PySide.QtNetwork import QNetworkAccessManager, QNetworkRequest, QNetworkReply


class Browser(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.network_manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
        self.network_manager.createRequest = self._create_request
        self.network_manager.finished.connect(self._request_finished)

        self.web_page = QWebPage()
        self.web_page.setNetworkAccessManager(self.network_manager)

        self.web_view = QWebView()
        self.web_view.setPage(self.web_page)

    def _create_request(self, operation, request, data):
        print data.readAll()
        reply = QNetworkAccessManager.createRequest(self.network_manager,
                                                    operation,
                                                    request,
                                                    data)
        return reply

    def _request_finished(self, reply):
        if not reply.error() == QNetworkReply.NoError:
            # request probably failed
            print reply.error()
            print reply.errorString()

    def _make_request(self, url):
        request = QNetworkRequest()
        request.setUrl(QUrl(url))
        return request

    def _urlencode_post_data(self, post_data):
        post_params = QUrl()
        for (key, value) in post_data.items():
            post_params.addQueryItem(key, unicode(value))

        return post_params.encodedQuery()

    def perform(self, url, method='GET', post_data=dict()):
        request = self._make_request(url)

        if method == 'GET':
            self.web_view.load(request)
        else:
            encoded_data = self._urlencode_post_data(post_data)
            request.setRawHeader('Content-Type',
                                 QByteArray('application/x-www-form-urlencoded'))
            self.web_view.load(request,
                               QNetworkAccessManager.PostOperation,
                               encoded_data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])
    browser = Browser()
    browser.perform('http://www.python.org', 'POST', {'test': 'value', 'anothername': 'gfdgfd'})
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you a lot Andrean, it works perfectly. I've been trying a lot of different things with no success and I now see it was actually less trivial than I thought it would. Again, thank you a ton! :)

Comment: well you could accept it as the right answer if you dont mind :)

Comment: @andrean please look this question as well-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37041316/see-post-request-in-webkitpyqt-python , i know it will not take more than a minute for you to solve the issue, thanks